# "any%" shows as "%any" in a .Net Windows Form label text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, symbols

I created a label in a Windows Forms solution with the text "any%", which shows up as "%any" in the design window and when running the application. How do I prevent this from happening?

I tried this programmatically as well as in the properties window, with the same outcome. Other symbols like @ # $ show the same behaviour.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried `any\%`?

Comment: Yes, it shows as "%\any" for some reason.

Comment: Also with a space in between ("any %"), it shows the space after the % ("% any").

Comment: Have you checked if the label has all the other properties set to the expected values, so they are not messing with the text?

Comment: Wild guess: have you tried any \\% ?

Comment: @Alicia - Yes, I created a new label and didn't change any of the properties except for the text "any%".

Comment: @Lajos Arpad - That shows as "%\\ any".

Comment: Another wild guess, did you try with any%% ?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - That shows as "% %any".

Comment: Strangely, with a number in front it shows normally: "100%" stays "100%"

Comment: What about %any%?

Comment: Haha, that shows up normally indeed, but "%any$" shows as "$any%".

Comment: Is the `RightToLeft` property set true on the label?

Comment: Actually, "%any" shows as "any%", so I got what I wanted now. Still would like to know what causes this odd behaviour.

Comment: @Crowcoder - That fixes it too, thank you! However, now the label is not aligned with the right edge anymore.

Comment: How do you have the `TextAlign` property set?

Comment: @Crowcoder - MiddleRight

Comment: All fixed now, I must've set AutoSize to True for that label.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Katun please delete the question or post the answer then